# Perf doesn't have language (python) support

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, perf

I am trying to use self built linux perf tool. perf source code comes with linux kernel source, I downloaded linux kernel sources and built and installed tools/perf via the command

`sudo make -C tools perf perf_install`

The build and install seems to proceed fine. I am interested in using python language support with perf data files - this is where I am hitting an issue

```
Auto-detecting system features:
---
...                                   dwarf: [ on  ]
...                      dwarf_getlocations: [ on  ]
...                                   glibc: [ on  ]
...                                  libbfd: [ on  ]
...                          libbfd-buildid: [ on  ]
...                                  libcap: [ on  ]
...                                  libelf: [ on  ]
...                                 libnuma: [ on  ]
...                  numa_num_possible_cpus: [ on  ]
...                                 libperl: [ on  ]
...                               libpython: [ on  ]
...                               libcrypto: [ on  ]
...                               libunwind: [ on  ]
...                      libdw-dwarf-unwind: [ on  ]
...                                    zlib: [ on  ]
...                                    lzma: [ on  ]
...                               get_cpuid: [ on  ]
...                                     bpf: [ on  ]
...                                  libaio: [ on  ]
...                                 libzstd: [ on  ]
---
  LINK    perf
  INSTALL binaries
  INSTALL tests
  INSTALL libexec
  INSTALL bpf-examples
  INSTALL perf-archive
  INSTALL perf-iostat
  INSTALL strace/groups
  INSTALL perl-scripts
  INSTALL python-scripts
  INSTALL dlfilters
  INSTALL perf_completion-script
  INSTALL perf-tip
```

However when I try to check language support withing perf,  I am seeing that none of the language support is build in

```
xxxx@myserver:~/master/saf/perf/001/dual_filter$ perf script -s lang

Scripting language extensions (used in perf script -s [spec:]script.[spec]):
<blank>
```

On a different system, when I check the language dupport (using the perf version that came with the distro), I see this

```
[root@server2 ~]# perf script -s lang

Scripting language extensions (used in perf script -s [spec:]script.[spec]):

  Perl                                       [Perl]
  pl                                         [Perl]
  Python                                     [Python]
  py                                         [Python]

[root@server2 ~]#
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running your newly-installed `perf`, not the system `/bin/perf`?

Comment: yes I verified that ... I ran it from the tools directory using ./perf

Comment: Is there anything in one of the README files? Good luck,